# Testing a web application?

Tags: testing, web

What are the test cases that can be used to test a web application?

1. test links
2. bench marking

any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions of the web application should be identified based on the specification and/or requirements (http://www.testingminded.com/2008/12/what-is-test-base.html). You can write test cases based on this function list. But there are a lot of ways to improve your tests... If you want to use a more sophisticated method, you can read about ISTQB, test planning and test desing. http://www.istqb.org/newsevents/news/2013/341-chapter-3-in-advanced-level-syllabus-2012-test-analyst-test-techniques.html

For webapp testing we use Selenium (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) and JUnit (http://junit.org/).